# Problem with downloading HD movies to Mac when syncing with iPad 3

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, ipad, movie

I bought several HD movies using iPad3, however when I try to sync my iPad with MacBook Air (i7, 13", Mid2012) they are downloaded with much lower resolution to my Mac.

I don't know also I this is connected, but I don't see them in iCloud (no iCloud icon next to them in iTunes, so I'm unable to re-download them once deleted, all I can do is to sync with iPad 3 but with low resolution)

Comment: What do you mean by lower resolution? 720p instead of 1080p? I'm sure that iTunes is copying what's on the iPad. I've never bought any movies from an iPad, but in iTunes, there's a setting to download content in either 720p or 1080p; perhaps that has been sent to the iTunes Store for your account? As for not seeing the cloud icon, that's odd. Do they show up in your Purchased list in the iTunes Store? You don't have two different iTunes Store accounts, do you?

Comment: I don't see any movies that I bought (neither the ones with bought with iTunes nor with iPad directly) and there is no video/movie in Purchased list, I can see only other items I bought like audio. The movie I bought HD and downloaded to mac is around 854x354px size only - its not stretched, the file size is also around half of the size what they say on iTunes page.  I have set in iTunes to download movies in 1080p and I have only one account.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the wrong file. Open iTunes and go to playback (iTunes > Preferences > Playback). Set it to play the HD (1080p) file by default. Just because it is the default downloaded HD version, doesn't mean that it will play that one by default.

Comment: I had this setting already set to the 1080p, it isn't the case it plays lo res because it donloaded lo res movie. When I left click the movie in iTunes and then "Show in finder" I see the low res movie file only. So the question in first place is why it doesn't download hd? I had 1080p set for both settings play and download but it does not work...

Comment: In the "Store" menu in iTunes, click on "Check for Available Downloads." It will notify you if you have yet to download a file you have bought.

Comment: It downloads all but movies :/